# How to add "more" button at the end of ListView to load more items?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView in which want to load 14 items at first and create a "more" link at the end of list of first 14 items and when pressing the "more" i have to load more 14 items and so on..
How can I add a button or link at the end of ListView which is only visible after scrolling to the bottom of ListView .. is there sutable tutorial somewhere or please suggest me the way out

Comment: the search word you are looking for is pagination. as in a paginated list.

Comment: Using FooterView will serve your purpose as explained by @Michele La Ferla below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use something similar to the code below:

```
// Create the Load More... button
Button btnLoadExtra = new Button(this);
btnLoadExtra.setText("Load More...");

// Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
lv.addFooterView(btnLoadExtra);

btnLoadExtra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Starting a new async task
        new loadMoreListView().execute();
    }
});
```

You then need to create a new class which creates an Async task to load the additional data:

```
private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                AndroidListViewWithLoadMoreButtonActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // increment current page
                current_page += 1;

                // Next page request
                URL = //enter the url for the extra data here.

                xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems.add(map);
                }

                // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
                int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                // Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(
                        AndroidListViewWithLoadMoreButtonActivity.this,
                        menuItems);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Setting new scroll position
                lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

            }
        });

        return (null);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // closing progress dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you implemented something nice today

Answer (score 1):

You can just pretend you always have one more item in the `getCount()` method, and then handle a click on the last ListView item.